# Can JsonServiceClient's OnUploadProgress be combined with .WithCache()?

Tags: c#, servicestack

In ServiceStack, you can create a JsonServiceClient and listen to the upload progress like this:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://api.example.org");
client.OnUploadProgress += (done, total) => {
};
```

However when combining this with caching:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://api.example.org").WithCache();
```

This won't work, because `WithCache()` returns a `IServiceClient` which doesn't implement `OnUploadProgress`.

**Is there a way I can use the `OnUploadProgress` while using `WithCache()`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WithCache()` extension method returns a an new instance of a `CachedServiceClient` which enhances the `JsonServiceClient` instance to manage a local HTTP Caching layer around GET Requests.

The `OnUploadProgress` is a callback to be notified of file uploads.

You can just configure the `JsonServiceClient` with what you need:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://api.example.org") {
    OnUploadProgress = (done, total) => ..
};
```

Then create the enhanced cache client off the modified instance, e.g:

```
var cacheClient = client.WithCache();
```

Comment: Why didn't think of this myself. Thanks, great explanation!